# Archive format with minimal rewrite support

Tags: compression

I need to store huge amount of text files. To reduce space consumption it were decided to store them in compressed format. But the problem is that they are often changed. So I can't just use zip, which as I understood rewrites modified tail of file.

I need some archive format which supports fast removal, append, update of files. For example as database does, leaving removed records intact until VACUUM is called.
Does anybody knows such format. Library with java interface would be awesome :)

Comment: If the files are sufficiently large, you could store them compressed per file (.txt.gz `GZipOutputStream` or .bz2 or whatever). That is what file systems are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put them in an archive. Just compress each file individually in a sub-directory on your file system. "fast removal, append, update of files" is exactly what file systems are designed for.

Compressing each file individually is all zip does, so the compression will be the same.